# Any idea what plant is this?

Tags: species-identification

[image: this]

I was asked by my biology teacher to find out it’s name but it seems like a pretty common plant to me so I have no idea how to start. Any idea what type of plant it is?

It was found in Malaysia in my school compound

Comment: If you know where and when this was found, this could be helpful extra information to add to your question.

Comment: can you kindly add the image of inflorescence, flower and fruit of this plant? close-up if possible. Dissecting a flower helps greatly.  also add a photograph of the whole plant, twigs and trunk.

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea how to start

You probably need an "identification key", or some kind of guide, that will help you identify the plant based on a series of questions or identification criteria.

To be able to use such keys or guides, you will need to familiarize yourself with technical vocabulary used in plant description. Some idea of the kind of ecosystem where the plant lives in would likely help too.

If the plant seems common, you will maybe find it on listings of common plants for your area.

Answer (score -1):

This branch of the plant look very similar to the Indian Curry Leaf plant -*Murraya koenigii*.

It is used as a spice, garnish and also as a taste enhancer in Indian cuisine. It grows in almost every Indian household in their gardens or kitchen for fresh use.

[image]

It could be some thing else too, I am a little bit unsure because the edges of the leaves look rough but in Indian Curry Plant, The leaf edges are smooth, Here are some pictures...

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps in guessing the species,

Best Wishes!

Comment: Leaf margins, as you say, do not match. Your answer also lacks citations and does not rectify why this Indian plant would be in Malaysia. Please avoid simply guessing and only answer if you can provide adequate support. Thanks

Comment: The Leaf Edges look rough, I agree to that but that could be due to the drying of the leaves for storage, also the Curry tree as it is called, is also found in Malayasia, as the growing conditions required for the plant as same for both the regions (India and Malayasia). Please avoid simply commenting by looking into the answer superficially.

Comment: but that's exactly my point. Your answer needs to be complete and stand on its own. The points I made in my previous comment are serious concerns when determining the validity of your ID. Such concerns should be met with cited support if you'd like to receive positive voting response here. Please see [help] and [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) and [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for further guidance. Thanks!